# How do I build an image carousel in CSS & jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So I want to get an understanding of how a carousel works, and what I need to know (specifically) when I am building one. E.g. what Math functions to use, and why.

Somethings I would like to be able to do with the carousel is change the number of images that you can see at once (starting with 1, and going up to MANY). As you increase the number of images, it should resize the others. Perhaps you can put an upper limit on the number of images that you can see at the same time.

Feel free to include HTML5 technologies, like local storage or anything that can make the carousel very lightweight, and fast.

Also, given that I have never done this before, I would love if you could break it down for me in various levels of complexity. Basic, Advanced, Complex, More Complex.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not delve into one of the existing carousel solutions?

Comment: The question is very broad, therefore, it's hard to give you a correct answer. Look at the example 'What' suggested. If something is not clear, you can ask a more focused question.

Comment: we're here to answer programming questions, not to do your programming homework.

Comment: @Pekka I tried many of them, and they were either too bulky, too difficult to customize to my particular needs, or had some other flaw. The only one that was decent was TinyCarousel, but even then, I was left wanting.

Comment: @Juan I will definitely do that. @zzzzBov this is a programming question. I am not 100% sure how to get started. All I am looking for is some guidance on the framework I would need to get started and how to move from there. If you had nothing constructive to add, you didn't have to say anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This site](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/automatic-image-slider-w-css-jquery/) has a tutorial on building a carousel with jQuery, which goes fairly in-depth and is quite clear.